# Firestore initial update is not recognized. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code, which is updating the number of likes on the movie. But the first update is not recognized. So if I click the button 5 times. On firestore is updated only 4.

```
async liked() {
            await db.collection('movies').doc(this.movie.id).update({
                likes: this.movie.likes++
            });
        },
```

I any more code needed I will update the question.

Comment: maybe you should disable the button until the update has been done.

Comment: and how specifically i would do that. if i can ask?

Comment: Se my answer for example. Now I dont know if you are using react or something else with the js so some little modification may be require to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Postfix increment (`x++`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#postfix_increment) changes the variable *after* evaluation, so your original code updates `likes` to the current value of `this.movie.likes` and then increments it.

That is, this code:

```js
await db.collection('movies').doc(this.movie.id).update({
  likes: this.movie.likes++
});
```

...is equivalent to:

```js
await db.collection('movies').doc(this.movie.id).update({
  likes: this.movie.likes
});
this.movie.likes += 1;
```

Conversely, [prefix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#prefix_increment) (`++x`) changes the variable *before* evaluation:

```js
await db.collection('movies').doc(this.movie.id).update({
  likes: ++this.movie.likes
});
```

...which is equivalent to:

```js
this.movie.likes += 1;
await db.collection('movies').doc(this.movie.id).update({
  likes: this.movie.likes
});
```

But it's probably clearer to increment the variable on its own line, as you've discovered in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, you need to increment the value before updating your document. However, I will give you another option which is to let Firestore increment the value for you. And doing it this way will protect against race conditions where multiple updates could come in at once.

Use the Firestore.FieldValue.increment operation in your update query. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment

Something like

```
async liked() {
            await db.collection('movies').doc(this.movie.id).update({
                likes: firebase.Firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needed to do the calculation before the update

```
async liked() {
            this.movie.likes++
            await db.collection('movies').doc(this.movie.id).update({
                likes: this.movie.likes
            });
        },
```